# Can't target active state of Nav items on Bootstrap v4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm working on a Navbar with some transitions. I can target the links, just not the active state for some reason. Where am I going wrong? Here's my HTML code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top py-0">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Studio</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#title_page">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#info">Information</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#program_mobile" id="navlink_lessson_program">Lesson Program</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And the CSS I'm using:

```
/*Underline animation*/
.navbar-nav a:after,
.navbar-nav .active a:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0px;
  height: .1em;
  margin-top: .04em;
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  transition: 1s;
}

.navbar-nav a:hover:after,
.navbar-nav .active a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
 }


/*Background animation on menu items*/
.navbar-nav a:hover,
.navbar-nav a:focus,
.navbar-nav .active a,
.navbar-nav .active a:hover,
.navbar-nav .active a:focus {
    color: #FFF !important;
    border-radius: .5em;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    transition: 1s ease;
}
```

Comment: What's the outcome you expect? What's supposed to happen?

Comment: What isn't working? I tested this in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ld70v41u/1/) and I see the background to dark when you select a `nav-item`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see here, the way you are targeting the `.active` link is wrong, since you are telling your CSS to look for a `.active` class element that has a `a` child. This does not occur on your document, you need to define it as a `a` tag that *has* the `.active` class, like: `a.active`

```css
/*Underline animation*/

.navbar-nav a:after,
.navbar-nav .active a:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0px;
  height: .1em;
  margin-top: .04em;
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  transition: 1s;
}

.navbar-nav a:hover:after,
.navbar-nav .active a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}


/*Background animation on menu items*/

.navbar-nav a:hover,
.navbar-nav a:focus,
.navbar-nav .active a,
.navbar-nav .active a:hover,
.navbar-nav .active a:focus {
  color: #FFF !important;
  border-radius: .5em;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  transition: 1s ease;
}

.navbar-nav a.active {
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top py-0">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Studio</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#title_page">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#info">Information</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#program_mobile" id="navlink_lessson_program">Lesson Program</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't figure this out for hours, it was driving me nuts. And it worked with Bootstrap v3, so I was very confused.

Comment: No problem :) in Bootstrap v3 its because the links are inside a `li` tag which is the one that has the `.active` classes, so they correctly target the children; in this case the markup's a bit different so you just need to look carefully at specificity :)

Comment: @funkyshizzle btw if this helped you consider marking it as an accepted answer or an upvote :)

Comment: Makes total sense now, I like the non-li option a lot better. Thanks! I even got the transition out of focus now to work too by using the :after pseudo selector.

Yes, I was looking for it and upvoted your answer but since I'm a new user, I don't think it registered. Now I noticed the check sign under the up/down vote arrows is actually clickable :)